# Python multithreading for file reading results in slower performance: How to optimize?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I am learning concurrency in Python and I have noticed that the `threading` module even lowers the speed of my code. My code is a simple parser where I read HTMLs from my local directory and output parsed a few fields as JSON files to another directory.

I was expecting a speed improvement but the speed becomes lower, tested with small numbers of HTMLs at a time, 50, 200, 1000, and large numbers of HTMLs like 30k. In all situations, the speed lowers. For example, with 1000 HTMLs without threading speed is ~2.9 seconds, with threading speed is ~4 seconds.

Also tried the `concurrent.futures` `ThreadPoolExecutor` but it provides the same slower results.

I know about GIL, but I thought that I/O-bound tasks should be handled with multithreading.

Here is my code:

```
import json
import re
import time
from pathlib import Path
import threading


def get_json_data(body: str) -> re.Match[str] or None:
    return re.search(
        r'(?<=json_data">)(.*?)(?=</script>)', body
    )


def parse_html_file(file_path: Path) -> dict:
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        html_content = file.read()
        match = get_json_data(html_content)
        if not match:
            return {}

        next_data = match.group(1)
        json_data = json.loads(next_data)

        data1 = json_data.get("data1")
        data2 = json_data.get("data2")
        data3 = json_data.get("data3")
        data4 = json_data.get("data4")
        data5 = json_data.get("data5")

        parsed_fields = {
            "data1": data1,
            "data2": data2,
            "data3": data3,
            "data4": data4,
            "data5": data5
        }

        return parsed_fields


def save_parsed_fields(file_path: Path, parsed_fields: dict, output_dir: Path) -> None:
    output_filename = f"parsed_{file_path.stem}.json"
    output_path = output_dir / output_filename

    with open(output_path, "w") as output_file:
        json.dump(parsed_fields, output_file)

    print(f"Parsed {file_path.name} and saved the results to {output_path}")


def process_html_file(file_path: Path, parsed_dir: Path) -> None:
    parsed_fields = parse_html_file(file_path)
    save_parsed_fields(file_path, parsed_fields, parsed_dir)


def process_html_files(source_dir: Path, parsed_dir: Path) -> None:
    parsed_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    threads = []
    for file_path in source_dir.glob("*.html"):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=process_html_file, args=(file_path, parsed_dir))
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    # Wait for all threads to finish
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()


def main():
    base_path = "/home/my_pc/data"
    source_dir = Path(f"{base_path}/html_sample")
    parsed_dir = Path(f"{base_path}/parsed_sample")

    start_time = time.time()

    process_html_files(source_dir, parsed_dir)

    end_time = time.time()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    print(f"Application took {duration:.2f} seconds to complete.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I know about asyncio, but I want to correctly test all of the multithreading methods to pick the best that suits me.

As mentioned tried also `concurrent.futures`, code is almost the same when processing html_files I have these lines:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
        # Iterate over the HTML files in the source directory
        for file_path in source_dir.glob("*.html"):
            executor.submit(process_html_file, file_path, parsed_dir)
```

Are there any mistakes in my code? How could I optimize my code better with multithreading (aside from asyncio)?

Comment: Concurrency isn't a magic button to speed code up -- you have to understand where and what the bottleneck is and address it accordingly. In your current implementation, I'd bet the concurrent reads and write of all the files slows things down b/c the disk now suddenly has to serve many simultaneous requests.

Comment: The only part of your code that multithreading could help is the reading of the file.  Almost the entirety of your code is Python code parsing strings.

Comment: With one thread reading data from a spinning drive, data is read in-order, which means the drive is likely to be able to read all of the data without often having to stop, seek the read/write-head to a new location, and then wait for the disk to spin around to the necessary location again.   With multiple threads reading at once, the data is being read out-of-order, which means disk-seeks are much more likely to occur and therefore overall throughput will be lower.  (Exceptions:  if the entire data set can fit in cache, or if you're reading from SSD, seeks shouldn't matter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can improve `parse_html_file` by closing the input file as soon as you read all the data (note that the rest of the code is not in the `with` context manager anymore):

```py
def parse_html_file(file_path: Path) -> dict:
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        html_content = file.read()
        
    match = get_json_data(html_content)
    if not match:
        return {}

    next_data = match.group(1)
    json_data = json.loads(next_data)

    data1 = json_data.get("data1")
    data2 = json_data.get("data2")
    data3 = json_data.get("data3")
    data4 = json_data.get("data4")
    data5 = json_data.get("data5")

    parsed_fields = {
        "data1": data1,
        "data2": data2,
        "data3": data3,
        "data4": data4,
        "data5": data5
    }

    return parsed_fields
```

Second, your solution which uses `threading` is not recommended as it will create as many threads as there are input file. This can be a lot and could results in slowdowns and high memory usage. The thread/process pool solution is better in this scenario. Make sure that `max_workers` is set to a value greater than 1 (for instance equal to the number of CPU cores of your computer).

Last, multithreading and multiprocessing are unlikely to speedup the execution of your program if the concurrently executing functions are very fast. In this case, you'll only pay the overhead of managing concurrency. You should first time finely the functions and identify the ones that are very slow (is it `get_json_data` or the rest of the instructions of `parse_html_file`, or maybe the file saving?).